# selecting data using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large catalog that I am selecting data from according to the following criteria:

```
columns = ["System", "rp", "mp", "logg"]
catalog = pd.read_csv('data.txt', skiprows=1, sep ='\s+', names=columns)

# CUTS
i = (catalog.rp != -1) & (catalog.mp != -1)

new_catalog = pd.DataFrame(catalog[i])
print("{0} targets after cuts".format(len(new_catalog)))
```

When I perform the above cuts the code is working fine. Next, I want to add one more cut: I want to select all the targets that have `4.0 < logg < 5.0`. However, some of the targets have `logg = -1` (which stands for the fact that the value is not available). Luckily, I can calculate `logg` from the other available parameters. So here is my updated cuts:

```
# CUTS
i = (catalog.rp != -1) & (catalog.mp != -1)
if catalog.logg[i] == -1:
    catalog.logg[i] = catalog.mp[i] / catalog.rp[i]
i &= (4 <= catalog.logg) & (catalog.logg <= 5)
```

However, I am receiving an error:
`if catalog.logg[i] == -1:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

Can someone please explain what I am doing wrong and how I can fix it. Thank you

### Edit 1

My dataframe looks like the following:

```
Data columns:
System           477  non-null values
rp               477  non-null values
mp               477  non-null values
logg             477  non-null values
dtypes: float64(37), int64(3), object(3)None
```

### Edit 2

```
 System  rp  mp  logg   FeH  FeHu  FeHl  Mstar  Mstaru  Mstarl  
0  target-01  5196     24     24  0.31  0.04  0.04  0.905   0.015   0.015   
1  target-02  5950    150    150 -0.30  0.25  0.25  0.950   0.110   0.110   
2  target-03  5598     50     50  0.04  0.05  0.05  0.997   0.049   0.049   
3  target-04  6558     44     -1  0.14  0.04  0.04  1.403   0.061   0.061   
4  target-05  6190     60     60  0.05  0.07  0.07  1.194   0.049   0.050   

....

[5 rows x 43 columns]
```

### Edit 3

My code in a format that I understand should be:

```
for row in range(len(catalog)):
    parameter = catalog['logg'][row]
    if parameter == -1:
        parameter = catalog['mp'][row] / catalog['rp'][row]
    if parameter > 4.0 and parameter < 5.0:
        # select this row for further analysis
```

However, I am trying to write my code in a more simple and professional way. I don't want to use the `for` loop. How can I do it?

### EDIT 4

Consider the following small example:

```
System     rp   mp    logg
target-01  2    -1     2     # will NOT be selected since mp = -1
target-02  -1    3     4     # will NOT be selected since rp = -1
target-03  7     6     4.3   # will be selected since mp != -1, rp != -1, and 4 < logg <5
target-04  3.2    15    -1   # will be selected since mp != -1, rp != -1, logg = mp / rp = 15/3.2 = 4.68 (which is between 4 and 5)
```

Comment: Could you show how is your dataframe looks like?

Comment: @AntonProtopopov, I edited the question. Please check it out. My `df` has more columns than the one I posted. I removed them for simplicity.

Comment: BTW What is `mp[i]` and `rp[i]`? Should it be as `catalog.mp[i]` and `catalog.rp[i]`?

Comment: yeah yeah, you are right! But still the errors persists. @AntonProtopopov

Comment: AIU you attach `describe` output but could you show actual data? Like `df.head(10)`?

Comment: @AntonProtopopov, please check edit number 2.

Answer (score 1):

you get the error because catalog.logg[i] is not a scalar,but a series,so you should turn to vectorized manipulation:

```
catalog.loc[i,'logg'] = catalog.loc[i,'mp']/catalog.loc[i,'rp']
```

which would modify the logg column inplace

As for edit 3:

```
rows=catalog.loc[(catalog.logg > 4) & (catalog.logg < 5)]
```

which will select rows that satisfy the condition

Comment: The error is from the `for` loop. I also tried `if catalog.loc[i, 'logg'] == -1:` and now the error I get is `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'loc'`

Comment: this same code works in my case, .loc is for slicing pandas dataframes,    `catalog.loc[i, 'logg'] == -1` is still a series,so you would still get the ambiguous truth value error, you should either iterate through the series one by one or use vectorized operations

Comment: Can you give me more details? I am new to `pandas` and I don't want to use a `for` loop.

Comment: `catalog.loc[i,'logg']` will return a sub-series of  logg column that the condition `i` is true, so you can directly modify this series by dividing respective sub-series `mp` by `rp`, the `/` taking to series will just do an element-wise division

Comment: I understand yet I do not know how to implement it. How did you fix the `for` loop?

Comment: you dont need the for loop anymore,the point of for loop is just to modify logg column

Comment: But there are certain targets that have a given `logg`. These targets I do not want to modify. I only want to calculate `logg` in case this parameter is not given in the original data (which is when logg = -1). Please check `edit 3` for further information.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of that code:

```
if catalog.logg[i] == -1:
    catalog.logg[i] = catalog.mp[i] / catalog.rp[i]
```

You could use following:

```
i &= df.logg == -1
df.loc[i, 'logg'] = df.loc[i, 'mp'] / df.loc[i, 'rp']
# or
df.ix[i, 'logg'] = df.ix[i, 'mp'] / df.ix[i, 'rp']
```

For your edit 3 you need to add that line:

```
your_rows = df[(df.logg > 4) & (df.logg < 5)]
```

Full code:

```
i = (catalog.rp != -1) & (catalog.mp != -1)
i &= df.logg == -1
df.ix[i, 'logg'] = df.ix[i, 'mp'] / df.ix[i, 'rp']
your_rows = df[(df.logg > 4) & (df.logg < 5)]
```

**EDIT**

Probably I still don't understand what you want, but I get your desired output:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = """
System     rp   mp    logg
target-01  2    -1     2     
target-02  -1    3     4     
target-03  7     6     4.3   
target-04  3.2    15    -1   
"""

catalog = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep='\s+')
i = (catalog.rp != -1) & (catalog.mp != -1)
i &= catalog.logg == -1
catalog.ix[i, 'logg'] = catalog.ix[i, 'mp'] / catalog.ix[i, 'rp']
your_rows = catalog[(catalog.logg > 4) & (catalog.logg < 5)]

In [7]: your_rows
Out[7]:
  System   rp  mp    logg
2  target-03  7.0   6  4.3000
3  target-04  3.2  15  4.6875
```

Am I still wrong?

Comment: It is not working. The `full code` you provided, the script is selecting all the targets that have `logg = -1`. That is not what I want.

Comment: So I didn't understand what you want.. AFAIU You need to select all `(catalog.rp != -1) & (catalog.mp != -1)` then replace all rows where `df.logg == -1` to `df.ix[i, 'mp'] / df.ix[i, 'rp']` and then choose all rows from modified `df` where `(df.logg > 4) & (df.logg < 5)`. What exactly do you want?

Comment: What I want is the following: First, I select all `(catalog.rp != -1) & (catalog.mp != -1). Second, IF `catalog.logg == -1`, replace `-1` by `catalog.mp / catalog.rp`. Third, select all the entries (from the newly modified AND original df) where `(catalog.logg > 4) & (catalog.logg < 5)`.

Comment: In `edit 4` I provided an example. Thank you for your patience.